# Is there a chat room for Wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Some stackexchange sites like StackOverflow have chat page. Does WordPress.stackexchange.com have something similar?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as I posted that I found the link in the footer. In StackOverflow the chat link is on the right side column.

Link to [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: we mostly chat in The Loop, the other chatrooms are mostly just people who had lots of comments and were prompted to move discussion to chat by the site

Comment: The link can also be found on the site-switcher from the top-right SE icon.